# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(2^n+3^n+4^n)z^n}$

Tags: calculus

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(2^n+3^n+4^n)z^n}$

It's been ages since I did this but I'm sure it was quite simple. All the notes I can find say use the ratio test. If it was just $2^n$ or just $3^n$ then I could do that but it's not. I'm really stuck so any help appreciated.

Comment: Note that $$4^n<2^n+3^n+4^n<3\cdot4^n$$Now can you tell what radius of convergence the left one and right one would give?

Comment: $4^n$ dominates, so $\frac14$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

Use Cauchy Hadamard theorem and Squeeze Theorem:

$${\frac {1}{R}}=\limsup _{n\to \infty }{\big (}|c_{n}|^{1/n}{\big )}$$

$$\limsup _{n\to \infty }(4^n)^{1/n}<\limsup _{n\to \infty }(2^n+3^n+4^n)^{1/n}<\limsup _{n\to \infty }(3\cdot4^n)^{1/n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Of the three exponentials, the $4^n$ term will be the dominant cause of the sequence's growth, so we ought to expect the ratio to be close to 4. Indeed, with this in mind, we form the ratio and divide the top and bottom by $4^n$ in an attempt to create a 4 in the numerator to pair with a 1 in the denominator. The rest of the proof concerns bounding the "small parts" left in this ratio, but the work is effectively done by this stage.

$a_n=2^n+3^n+4^n\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}+4^{n+1}}{2^n+3^n+4^n}=\frac{2(2/4)^n+3(3/4)^n+4}{(2/4)^n+(3/4)^n+1}\to \frac{0+0+4}{0+0+1}=4$

More generally, if you have a sequence which is a sum of terms with different growth rates, then the sequence's overall growth rate is that of the fastest-growing component. Formally:

Suppose $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to A$ and $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\to B$, where $\vert A \vert > \vert B \vert$. Then $\frac{a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}}{a_{n}+b_{n}}\to A$

(Technically should be a bit more careful with the denominator here, though as it's a limit we just have to know that for sufficiently large $n$, the denominator is nonzero. Given the sequences grow at distinct rates, we can easily convince ourselves of this)